# Using back / menu / search button in android phone

Tags: jquery, android, html, cordova

I'm developing android application using HTML5, jQuery and Phonegap. But i'm not able to use the back/menu/search button of android phone. I've gone through the documentation of phonegap. But still no luck. How should I handle them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because, the previous version of phonegap before 0.9.6 doesn't support these event types.

Answer (score 2):

In this documentation you see your answer: http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/29494136/Android%20Back%20Button%20Handler

```
// This is your app's init method. Here's an example of how to use it
function init() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDR, false);
} 
function onDR(){
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", backKeyDown, true);
    //boot your app...
}
function backKeyDown() { 
    // do something here if you wish
    // alert('go back!');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. I've been trying above example for long but couldn't get the result. Can you please provide complete example?